# SQL Query return a column per hour / day / week / month betwen 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I am trying to achieve (Table View)

```
 Part No   01/02/15  02/02/15  03/02/15  04/02/15  05/02/15  06/02/15
 PU1234        24       25        15         22       27        21
 PU5678        25       22        19         21       24        26
```

Table of Data

```
 A   B  C   D           E         Part Name     Date & Time     
FX01 FN50   X82 OP.70   Packing   PU4238TZA     2015-02-27 03:43:55.000
FX01 FN50   X82 OP.70   Packing   PU4238TZA     2015-02-27 03:43:56.000
FX01 FN50   X82 OP.70   Packing   PU4238TZA     2015-02-27 03:43:57.000
FX01 FN50   X82 OP.70   Packing   PU4238TZA     2015-02-27 03:43:58.000
```

I want the code to be generic so I can manipulate it to achieve all of the below

- Quantity per part number per hour (24 hour period) stored procedure 1
- Quantity per part number per day (between two dates) stored procedure 2
- Quantity per part number per week (between two dates) stored procedure 3
- Quantity per part number per Month (between two dates) stored procedure 4

The code below works (to a fashion) but populates the table with all zero's

```
`;with cte as(
select 
    [CAB Part No.], cast([Date & Time] as date) UtcDay, DATEPART(hour, [Date & Time]) UtcHour, count(*) as Counts
from  [dbo].[SFDLOG]
where [Date & Time] between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-02'
group by
    cast([Date & Time] as date), DATEPART(hour,[Date & Time]),[CAB Part No.]
)
select dateadd(hour, utchour, cast(utcday as datetime)) as [SFD Hour],       
Counts
into #TempDates
from cte

select *
from
(
select [CAB Part No.],[SFD Hour],
    convert(CHAR(10),[SFD Hour], 120) PivotDate
from #tempDates
left join [SFDLOG]
    on [SFD Hour] between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-02'
 ) x
 pivot
 (
count([SFD Hour])
for PivotDate in ([2015-02-01 00:00:00.000], [[2015-02-01 01:00:00.000], 2015-02-01 02:00:00.000],        
 ) p;
 drop table #tempdates`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it to work, below is the answer. Thanks to everyone that replied.

```
;with cte as(
select  [CAB Part No.]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[Date & Time]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,cast([Date & Time] as date) UtcDay
        ,DATEPART(hour, [Date & Time]) UtcHour
from    [SFDLOG]
where   [Date & Time] between '2015-02-1' and '2015-02-2'   

)
select  [CAB Part No.]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,dateadd(hour, utchour, cast(utcday as datetime)) as [SFD Hour]
into #TempDates
from cte

select *
from
(
select   [Quantity]
        ,[SFD Hour]
        ,[CAB Part No.]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
from #tempDates
) x
pivot
(
count([Quantity])
for [SFD Hour]
In ([2015-02-01 00:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 01:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 02:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 03:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 04:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 05:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 06:00:00:000]
    ,[2015-02-01 07:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 08:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 09:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 10:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 11:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 12:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 13:00:00:000]
    ,[2015-02-01 14:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 15:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 16:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 17:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 18:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 19:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 20:00:00:000]
    ,[2015-02-01 21:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 22:00:00:000],[2015-02-01 23:00:00:000])
)p

Order By [CAB Part No.],[Process No.]

drop table #tempdates
```